# Is there a way to disable a specific event in kendo ui scheduler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am working with Kendo UI, js and the scheduler component.

My question is, if there is a way to disable a specific event from scheduler.

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172685/how-to-disable-events-in-kendo-ui-scheduleri-just-to-make-it-read-only), but this disables all events in scheduler. I want to disable just a specific event. The code should be something like this>

```
function disableEvents()
{
    var data = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.data();
    data.forEach(function(event){
          if(event.ID='2') 
          {
               event.disable = true; //I have tried with event.editable = true;
          }
    });
}
```

I can't find the property editable nor disable, or something like that. Maybe there is a way to disable it using jquery. Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to implement all the events specified in the restriction example of Kendo and preventDefault behaviour where ever your condition is not successfully.

For reference: **[Kendo Restriction Events Description](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/restriction)**.

You will need to take care of all the events (i.e. edit, save, resize, move) if you want to disable any event from any changes. The events are as below:

```
    resize: function(e) {
        if (e.event.meetingID = 1) {
            this.wrapper.find(".k-marquee-color").addClass("invalid-slot");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    move: function(e) {
        if (e.event.meetingId = 1) {
            this.wrapper.find(".k-event-drag-hint").addClass("invalid-slot");
        }
    },
    save: function(e) {
        if (e.event.meetinID = 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
   edit: function (e) {
        if (e.event.meetinID = 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

I have updated the Kendo Restriction example with your condition: **[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@D_Learning/EPuN)**

Answer (score 2):

Use the event event's `preventDefault` method:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
    views: ["day", "month"],
    dataSource: [{
        id: 1,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
        title: "Interview editable"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        start: new Date("2013/6/6 06:00 AM"),
        end: new Date("2013/6/6 07:00 AM"),
        title: "Interview not editable"
    }],
    edit: function (e) {
        if (e.event.id === 2) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/8F3N7/3/))